# Permission denied when trying to install easy_install on OSX

Tags: python, macos, installation, easy-install

I'm trying to install easy_install and, well... see for yourself:

---

sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg

Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg

Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages

Adding setuptools 0.6c11 to easy-install.pth file

Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin

**error: /usr/local/bin/easy_install: Permission denied**

---

How do I give my computer permission to do this? I tried telling it in a friendly voice, "computer, I hereby grant you permission to install easy_install" but that didn't work.

Comment: +1, primarily because the title amused me :)

Comment: +1, recalling my own "easy"_install frustration under (an older) OS X - calling `easy_install` after upgrading via `easy_install -U setuptools` continued to run the *old* version since the new script got dumped in /usr/local/bin which came after /usr/bin in `$PATH`. Took me a while to figure out what was going on...

Comment: Did you try turning on voice recognition in System Preferences?? And perhaps you need to be more firm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [sudo](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sudo).

```
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

I would also investigate [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Edit (5 years later): I now suggest [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead of MacPorts.

Comment: I want to like MacPorts, but when I tried it for a particular library I wanted in PHP I realized that MacPorts wants to suck down an entire ecosystem

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @peter you should try then homebrew. It tries to use the libraries that come with Mac os when possible. Also, it do not need to use sudo

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use sudo . You will need to enter your password.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the paths displayed, you are likely using the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 in OS X 10.6.  If so, be aware that Apple has already easily installed `easy_install` for you in `/usr/bin`.  Just try typing `easy_install`; you may need to use `sudo easy_install` if the package tries to install a script.  If you are using another Python (one you installed yourself), you will need to install a separate version of `setuptools` (or the newer `Distribute`) for it.